# Question about Conservation of Momentum

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

I have what I believe is a simple question about the conservation of momentum, but I'm not sure what the answer is.

I'm wondering when a stationary ballistic pendulum collides perfectly inelastically with a bullet at an angle (where the bullet's velocity isn't purely horizontal), is all of the bullet's momentum conserved or only its horizontal momentum.

My understanding of conservation of momentum comes from Newton's second law, where $\vec{F}=\frac{d\vec{p}}{dt}$ meaning $\vec{F}=0 \Rightarrow \vec{p}=\vec{k}$ for some constant vector k, and because this is a vector equation, I'm assuming horizontal and vertical components can be considered separately, and only horizontal momentum is conserved. This also makes intuitive sense because the pendulum's swing is basically horizontal after it's hit.

Is this reasoning correct? If not, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Is the pendulum swinging when it is hit, or is it stationary?

Comment: It's stationary, I'll edit the post to make that more clear

Comment: How is the pendulum connected to the pivot point, by a rope or a rigid rod? Do you know the bullet's angle exactly?

Comment: The attachment to the ceiling is by a rigid rod (not changing shape, just swinging) and the angle is an arbitrary acute angle. Does the measure of the angle change the final result?

Comment: Well, first think about different angles if it had been a rope instead. Then think about how that changes with a rigid rod, and also think about what that says about the vertical momentum component in both cases.

Comment: After considering the difference between a rigid rod and a rope, I think the "rigidity of the rod" applies a vertical tension force. As for the effect of changing the angle of the bullet, the only effect I can think of is steeper angles will have a larger vertical component and a smaller horizontal component, meaning the pendulum will swing less

Comment: @ParadoxicalPotato The tension of the rod is where I was getting at. And for the angle, before knowing the pendulum was on a rod and not a rope I was considering the case where the bullet is going upwards (in which case the rope could get slack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fact that in reality momentum is conserved in all directions even during an inelastic collision, if you could track and measure the momentum of every particle and object involved. However, these sorts of textbook problems frequently have some conventional assumptions that, IMO, aren't well stated and are misleading to students. In this case there are generally two major assumptions:

- The pivot point of the pendulum will not break. It's attached to a wall, or the ceiling, and thus indirectly to the Earth. Otherwise, the pendulum might not actually swing if pushed horizontally (and instead just dragging the floating pivot point behind it)
- The connection between the pivot point and the pendulum body is rigid against deformation in one or both directions. I.e., if the pivot point is a rope, it cannot stretch. If it is a rigid rod, as it has been clarified is the case for this particular problem, it also cannot be compressed.

Together, these unstated assumptions mean that all components of momentum may not necessarily be conserved within the conventions of the problem, because the model doesn't permit figuring out how the pendulum's rope or rigid rod, or the pivot point, or the ceiling, or the walls, or the Earth will move in response to an arbitrary impulse.

Comment: This clarifies a lot, but I'm still not entirely certain about the actual result of the experiment. If the rod is solid, does the tension in the rod change when the pendulum is hit by the bullet since before the collision the tension must have been equal in magnitude to the weight of the bob, but after the collision, it has to "stop" the bullet's vertical velocity? And does making the rod rigid mean that after the impact, there is no vertical velocity? This question isn't from a textbook, so unfortunately I don't have a "correct" answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are different possible scenarios here that can give slightly different results. Both the horizontal and vertical momentum is conserved in all scenarios

One is that the pendulum is hanging with a rigid material, connected to a pivot in the ceiling. In that case the horizontal momentum will be transferred to the pendulum, and the vertical momentum will be transferred to the earth. This is because the pendulum is connected to the ceiling, which in turn is connected to a house or building, which is connected to the earth, and the rigid materials cannot bend or be deformed.

The second is that the the pendulum is connected using a material like a rope, that can bend but not stretch(even it does slightly it is negligible). In that case two things can happen depending on the angle of the bullet. If the bullet is angled downwards, the horizontal momentum will be transferred to the pendulum, and the downward component of the momentum will be transferred to the earth. This is because the rope cannot stretch. If it is angled slightly upwards, both the horizontal and upward momentum will be transferred to the pendulum. This will happen because the rope will bend upwards creating a 'compression' because the distance in a straight line between the joint at the top and the pendulum will decrease. So it will move back, and also have a slightly higher upward momentum. But the path of the pendulum will no longer be purely radial to the pivot, but instead a combination of radial and vertical

Answer (score -1):

In short, the momentum must be conserved in all directions.

Let $m$ and $M$ be the masses of the bullet and the pendulum respectively, and let the bullet approach and hit the pendulum at velocity $\mathbf{v_i}$. The collision is perfectly inelastic, so the two masses will stick together and move -- instantaneously after colliding -- with a combined velocity $\mathbf{v_f}$. From the conservation of linear momentum,
$$m \mathbf{v_i} = (m+M) \mathbf{v_f}.$$ Assuming the collision lies in a plane, this is now a vector problem in 2 dimensions. Accordingly, we can it split into two equations:
$$m \mathrm{v_{i,x}} = (m+M) \mathrm{v_{f, x}},$$ and
$$m \mathrm{v_{i, y}} = (m+M) \mathrm{v_{f,y}}.$$ If you know the bullet's angle of impact, say an angle $\theta$ with respect to the horizontal (assuming it is moving toward the right initially and inclined upward: we can define these components of its velocity as being positive in the $x$ as well as the $y$ direction), you can substitute $\mathrm{v_{i,x}} = v_i \cos{\theta},$ and  $\mathrm{v_{i,x}} = v_i \sin{\theta}$ in the above and solve for $\mathrm{v_{f, x}}$ and $\mathrm{v_{f, y}}$.

Comment: I believe this answer is missing some important particularities of this problem, which granted aren't perfectly stated in the text (through no fault of the OP, as its tied up with the very nature of the question). In particular, these sorts of textbook problems tend to have some unstated assumptions that aren't well defined (in this case, about the behavior of the pendulum's pivot point and its rigid rod).

Comment: @jwimberley I am assuming you are referring to the fact that the pendulum is tied to a rope and fixed to a point. In my answer I only solved for the instantaneous combined speed of the bullet and the pendulum.

Comment: Actually the OP has clarified that the pendulum is attached by a rigid rod. But even if it were a rope, whtat if the bullet was traveling downwards? Does the problem assume that the rope can stretch? IMO these textbook problems are riddled with conventional assumptions that can mislead and confuse students if they aren't explained well.

Comment: @jwimberley I see your point (and I will update my earlier comment to reflect the rod); I was assuming this was a standard textbook problem and therefore did not consider such nuances.

Comment: I get that when you say you're only solving for the instantaneous velocity you're saying that of course the rope's tension might change that afterwards, and you're right -- but I don't think that's the answer that the textbook expects from the students. I think it actually expects them to say that only the horizontal component of momentum is conserved, and so that answer is the more nuanced/correct one.